# How do you make an Angular 2 component destroy itself?

Tags: angular, components

I am creating multiple dropdown menu components with a button in the parent, but I want those components to have buttons which destroy themselves. I'm sure it's simple, but can't seem to find anything that will do it. I know how to destroy it from the parent, but can't seem to do it from within. Anyone know? And just before it's destroyed, how can I send a message to the parent letting it know? (I have instances of them in the parent, but there are other things in the parent that need a signal)

I'm creating them dynamically using `viewContainerRef.createComponent`. Template looks like this:

```
<template item-host></template>
```

I tried an @Output and got this:

```
<template item-host [ERROR ->](destroyCheck)="someMethod($event)"></template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare a output variable

```
@Output() destroyCheck:EventEmitter<string>=new EventEmitter<string>();

ngOnDestroy(){

          this.destroyCheck.emit('destroyed');

}
```

In your parent component handle this way.

```
<div>
     <child-comp (destroyCheck)="someMethod($event)"> </child-comp>
</div>
```

Your method should be handled as

```
someMethod(something){
  console.log(something);
}
```

Comment: This would definitely work normally and looks good. I'm using `<template item-host></template>` though and it is giving errors. I updated the question.

Comment: `<template>` is a default html tag and you cannot use it for custom components.

Comment: maybe i am missing something, but the question was how to destroy component, and answer shows how to _notify parent_ AFTER being destroyed(how is unanswered)?

Answer (score 7):

use ComponentRef.destroy()

if you creating components dynamically using viewContainerRef.createComponent then you can destroy it with ComponentRef.destroy(). all you need is view reference to itself in the component, like in the example :

parent:

```
...
const componentRef = this.placeholder.createComponent(
  this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(SOMECOMP));
componentRef.instance.viewRef = componentRef;
...
```

child:

```
viewRef: ComponentRef<SOMECOMP>;
...
this.viewRef.destroy();
...
```

Comment: It works fine.Is it ok from architect/angular approach point of view?